# Creating a Web UI for WCF application

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core

I have a WCF application hosted as Windows service. It exposes API's which can be called from a desktop application. I would want to call the same API and show the information in Web interface also.

How can I achieve this?

Can I use ASP.NET core on top of WCF service or what is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Simply call your WCF services from within your ASP.NET Core application. So your web application becomes a client for your WCF service, and the end user is a client of your web application.

Comment: If i don't want to use the ASP.NET core, can I call the WCF service API's from Web application?

Comment: If the WCF services are accessible, you can call them from whatever you like.

Comment: Can the same WCF service(hosted in Windows service using net.tcp) be called from Angular framework? If so can anyone direct the example?

Comment: You _could_ do that but usually WCF services are hosted as SOAP and that will be a pain to use from the browser. You should consider adding a REST layer in front then so that you can call a REST API and that will then forward the request to your WCF service.

Comment: @poke, Thanks for the help and prompt replies. I was able to access the same WCF service by adding webHttpBinding and exposing the OperationContracts as WebGet and/or WebPut methods